# How to print Matlab's DURATION

Tags: matlab, time

Matlab has recently introduced a new type—duration. So I can do something like:

```
>> d = datetime('12:10:00') - datetime('12:05:00')
d = 
   00:05:00
>> whos d
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class       Attributes
  d         1x1               128  duration
```

Now I'd like to output a result of some calculation, which is of `duration` type, using `fprintf`. However `duration` is neither a number nor a string, nor does it have a method to create a string. What can I do to make `fprintf` accept it?

I am with Matlab 2014b.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
>> d_char = char(d);
>> whos d_char
   Name        Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

   d_char      1x8                16  char
```

Comment: I think this is more in line with that the OP is after

Answer (score 2):

It looks like disp is overriden for duration variables, perhaps you can piggyback on that:

```
ld = duration(1,2,3);
>> ld
ld = 
   01:02:03
>> fprintf('%s', ld)
Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'duration' inputs. . 
>> disp(ld)
   01:02:03
>> c = evalc('disp(ld)')
c =
   01:02:03
>> fprintf('%s', evalc('disp(ld)'))
   01:02:03
```

Comment: Eval is evil :) Thanks for the hack though.

Comment: obviously, the char solution is better:)

Answer (score 0):

There are functions to convert from `duration` type to a `double` number representing seconds, or minutes, etc. See for example [here](http://es.mathworks.com/help/finance/second.html).

Using your example,

```
>> d = datetime('12:10:00') - datetime('12:05:00')
d = 
   00:05:00
>> seconds(d)
ans =
   300
>> minutes(d)
ans =
     5
>> hours(d)
ans =
    0.0833
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've done so far. But it's really cumbersome :)