# Displaying to nearest minute with MATLAB's "duration" data type

Tags: matlab, datetime, formatting, duration

If I have a `duration` variable with the display format `'hh:mm'` then the time is truncated instead of rounded when displaying its value, e.g.

```
d = seconds(59); % Duration object for 59 secs, or 00:00:59 in hh:mm:ss format

d.Format = 'hh:mm';

disp(d)
>> d = 00:00
```

Is there any way to change the display format to *round* to the nearest display unit (in this case minutes) instead of truncating? In this example I'd expect to see `d = 00:01`.

Conversions to char [or other display methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31244810/how-to-print-matlabs-duration) yield the same output, e.g. `char(d)` / `fprintf('%s',d)`.

The only alternative I can see is some manual hack like

```
d2 = round(d,'minutes');   % >> 00:01:00
d2.Format = 'hh:mm';       % >> 00:01
disp(d2);
```

Note that I have to re-set the `Format` after rounding because it doesn't inherit the format from `d`.

I couldn't see this behaviour documented either way as "expected" in the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html), so in my opinion the current implementation seems like unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I don't have a solution; I only note that the docs describe the hh:mm format as a ["in the form of a digital timer"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-display-format-of-date-and-time-arrays.html?searchHighlight=digital%20timer&s_tid=srchtitle_digital%20timer_16), and not rounding is the behavior I expect from a timer (e.g., a stopwatch doesn't round up minutes).

Comment: Truncation seems to be baked into all of the duration/datetime code, for example the [SSS format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html?searchHighlight=truncates&s_tid=srchtitle_datetime%20format%20truncates_1#buhzxmk-1-Format) explicitly truncates instead of rounding. So anyway, I think you have to roll your own here.

Comment: Thanks I'd missed that line, I guess that at least gives it some justification, hadn't thought of that application

Comment: Another potential hack could be to add 30 seconds when displaying - that should result in the `duration` being "truncated" to the nearest minute